# Icons and alt showing up instead of photos on website deployed with Heroku and goorm used as environment

Tags: html, image, heroku, directory

Here is my code:

```
<img class="img-fluid my-3" src="/views/blueheadband.jpg" alt="hate this">
```

Now I have tried just doing "blueheadband.jpg" as the src and then put the file in the same area as the HTML. Below is the file directory.

[image]

I don't understand why it doesn't work. My website uses goorm as the environment and Heroku to deploy.

Comment: Is your website hosted on a subfolder? The preceding slash in `/views/blueheadband.jpg` changes the path to `yourdomain.com/views/blueheadband.jpg` instead of `yourdomain.com/yoursubfolder/views/blueheadband.jpg`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I found the issue. I wasn't selecting the public folder that used app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public")) to serve static assets with express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I wasn't selecting the public folder that used `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))` to serve static assets with express.